# Library not Loaded error (iOS)

Tags: ios, crash

I can run the app on the simulator but not on my device.  When it loads, it crashes, saying "dyld:  Library not loaded".  I do not have bitcode enabled as well.  I havent changed anything to my project, only difference is I am using a different mac.  What is the cause of this issue?  I am running Xcode 7.3.1 and El Capital version 10.11.6

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AMPopTip.framework/AMPopTip
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF7A196F-72AB-4020-BE2E-AC020641F112/TimeLoop.app/TimeLoop
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF7A196F-72AB-4020-BE2E-AC020641F112/TimeLoop.app/Frameworks/AMPopTip.framework/AMPopTip: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF7A196F-72AB-4020-BE2E-AC020641F112/TimeLoop.app/Frameworks/AMPopTip.framework/AMPopTip'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF7A196F-72AB-4020-BE2E-AC020641F112/TimeLoop.app/Frameworks/AMPopTip.framework/AMPopTip: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF7A196F-72AB-4020-BE2E-AC020641F112/TimeLoop.app/Frameworks/AMPopTip.framework/AMPopTip'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF7A196F-72AB-4020-BE2E-AC020641F112/TimeLoop.app/Frameworks/AMPopTip.framework/AMPopTip: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF7A196F-72AB-4020-BE2E-AC020641F112/TimeLoop.app/Frameworks/AMPopTip.framework/AMPopTip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out answer:
If you accidentally reset your keychain, this can occur due to missing Apple certificates in the keychain. I followed the answer on this to solve my problem.

I had the same issue and was able to fix by re-downloading the WWDR (Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority). Download from here: http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer